# SimpleJDBCCall handle out paramater with resultset

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using spring jdbc. I want result set with out param. separately i done but together i am not able to do.

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`%` PROCEDURE `client_xxxx`(
    IN p_xxxx TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED,
    IN p_result SMALLINT(2) UNSIGNED,
    OUT p_result BIT ) BEGIN 
       IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM xxx WHERE xxx = 1 AND xxx = 1) THEN
           SELECT ...;
           SET p_result = 0;
       ELSE
         SELECT ...;
         SET p_result = 1;
       END IF;
    END
```

**spring jdbc code**

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall =  new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName(sp);
List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) jdbcCall.execute(paramsArray).get("#result-set-1");
```

`list` get the result set with result set how can i get `p_result` with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [morejdbc](https://github.com/seregamorph/morejdbc) (available in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.seregamorph/morejdbc)) to call your procedure, it's more laconic and it's type safe:

```java
import static org.morejdbc.SqlTypes.BIGINT;
import static org.morejdbc.NamedJdbcCall.call;
import org.morejdbc.*;
...
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
...
Out<Integer> out = Out.of(INTEGER);
jdbcTemplate.execute(call("client_xxxx")
    .in("p_xxxx", pValue)
    .out("p_result", out));

System.out.println("Result is " + out.get());
```

For `ref_cursor` out parameter and Oracle database you can use

```java
Out<List<Record>> out = Out.of(OracleSqlTypes.cursor((rs, idx) -> new Record(rs)));
jdbcTemplate.execute(call("client_xxxx")
    .in("p_xxxx", pValue)
    .out("p_result", out)); // will auto-close ref-cursor

System.out.println("Got result records: " + out.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it in simple way that i miss.

```
public Map<String, Object> xxx(String sp, Object... paramsArray) {
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall =  new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName(sp);
    return jdbcCall.execute(paramsArray);
}
```

`execute()` gives two parameters default 
i.e. 
1) #result-set-1 
2) #update-count-1

`#result-set-1` result set i.e. `select record`
and `#update-count-1` returns update count. If we want to access result with `select` statement with `out` parameter. we just have to declare `out` parameter. `execute()` gives all the things in `Map<String, Object>` type.
So from map we can get all the multiple values that `stored procedure` returns.

For example my `SP` like

```
PROCEDURE xxx(
    IN xxxxTINYINT(1) UNSIGNED,
    IN xxxSMALLINT(2) UNSIGNED,
    OUT p_isconfig BIT
)
BEGIN
  SELECT....
  SET p_isconfig = 1;
END
```

So in `#result-set-1` i get select result.
and `p_isconfig` gives me result to. If you have any confusion then you can iterate map and identify that how get return parameters.

```
Iterator i = map.keySet().iterator();
while ( i.hasNext() ) {
   String key = (String) i.next();
   String value = params.get( key );

   System.out.println("key: " + key + " --- value: " + value) ;
```

}

This way i found solution after reading many things. If any one have other option for this solution then please share with me.

Comment: But It's not ResultSet It's a list of maps.